# Jackson FasterXML POJO A XML list

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml

Uso FasterXML Jackson para convertir un POJO a XML pero quiero que los hijos del tag padre de la lista tengan un nombre diferente. Como puedo hacerlo?

```
ORDEN:

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "eOrden") 
public class Orden {               
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "General")
   private General general = new General();
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Domicilio")
   private List<Domicilio> eDomicilio = new ArrayList<>();
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "eTarjetasLinea")
   private List<ETarjetasLinea> tarjetasLinea = new ArrayList<>();
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ElementosADSL")
   private ElementosADSL elementosADSL;
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Red")
   private Red red;
}


DOMICILIO:

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "eDomicilio")
public class Domicilio {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TipoDomicilio")
    private String tipoDomicilio;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Central")
    private String identificadorCalle;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "IdentificadorCalle")
    private String calle;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Calle")
    private String numero;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Colonia")
    private String colonia;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "CP")
    private String cp;
}

Cuando pruebo con esto arroja lo siguiente:

<eOrden xmlns="">
    <General />
    <Domicilio >
        <Domicilio>
            <TipoDomicilio />
            <Central />
            <IdentificadorCalle />
            <Calle />
            <Colonia />
            <CP />           
        </Domicilio>
    </Domicilio>
    <eTarjetasLinea></eTarjetasLinea>
    <ElementosADSL />
    <Red />
</eOrden>

Pero requiero que el tag hijo de Domicilio sea eDomicilio:

<eOrden xmlns="">
    <General />
    <Domicilio >
        <eDomicilio>
            <TipoDomicilio />
            <Central />
            <IdentificadorCalle />
            <Calle />
            <Colonia />
            <CP />           
        </eDomicilio>
    </Domicilio>
    <eTarjetasLinea></eTarjetasLinea>
    <ElementosADSL />
    <Red />
</eOrden>
```

Alguna idea de como cambiarlo? 
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hay una opción para cambiar el nombre del campo para cuando no puedes editar una clase de otra persona o cuando no quieres ensuciar la clase poniendo anotaciones por todos lados:

[Jackson MixIns](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

Comment: Que tal, tengo acceso a las clases, lo que necesito es cambiar el nombre de los tags hijos de un padre.